# When is this LINQ query executed?

Tags: c#, linq

```
public class TestClass
{
    public TestClass(int id, string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        Id = id;
    }
    public string Name
    { get; private set; }

    public int Id
    { get; private set; }

    public string Tag
    { get; set; }

    public DateTime Time
    { get; set; }
}

 private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<TestClass> list = new List<TestClass>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
        {
            TestClass t = new TestClass(i, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
            t.Tag = i%2 == 0?"Hello":"World";
            list.Add(t);
        }

        var query = list
            .GroupBy(l=>l.Tag);

        Func<IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, TestClass>>, int[]> func = GetIds<string,TestClass>;

        func.BeginInvoke(query, null, null);

        Console.Read();
    }

    private static int[] GetIds<T, U>(IEnumerable<IGrouping<T, U>> query)
    {
        List<int> ints = new List<int>();

        foreach(var y in query)
            ints.Add(y.Count());

        return ints.ToArray();
    }
}
```

I know LINQ doesnt execute until the collection is iterated, but i just want to make sure that I can assume that it still holds true even if the query is passed to another method async.

Comment: Remember, the query is nothing more than _an object which represents the query_.  Think of it like a SQL query string, just way smarter.  Passing a query string around doesn't execute the query; executing the query executes the query.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, query execution is still deferred. The query is just a reference to an implementation of `IEnumerable<T>` which in turn knows about another `IEnumerable<T>` (along with appropriate delegates for filtering, grouping etc).

Note that if you iterate over it a second time (in whatever thread) that will execute the query again. The query reference knows *how to get the data* - it doesn't know the data itself.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand it, it will still hold true asynchronously, however the execution may not be threadsafe. LINQ to SQL's DataContexts for example aren't threadsafe, and therefore LINQ to SQL queries should not be executed in another thread in that manner.

Answer (score 2):

The following illustration shows the complete query operation. In LINQ the execution of the query is distinct from the query itself,See below.

[image]

Source :: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397906.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It is executed when you call `ints.ToArray();` shouldn't matter that it in a different thread...

**EDIT:** I stand corrected, It would execute in the ForEach...

Comment: Well, it's iterated in the "foreach" bit - by the time `ToArray` is called, the query has completed and is irrelevant to `ints`.